# Angular does not fully render page after navigate

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to *Stack overflow* and I've got a problem with Angular 11. When I enter the dashboard from the login page, the dashboard will not be fully rendered and the page must be refreshed once for the dashboard to be fully rendered.

The pictures below shows the content before and after page refresh:

- [before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26IeK.jpg)
- [after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSxqA.jpg)

**login.component.ts** file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { tap, delay, finalize, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { AuthService } from '../../../../../app/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  error: string;
  isLoading: boolean;
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  get f () {
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }

  login() {
    this.isLoading = true;


    const credentials = this.loginForm.value;

    this.authService.login(credentials)
      .pipe(
        delay(20),
        tap(user => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home']) ),
        finalize(() => this.isLoading = false),
        catchError(error => of(this.error = error))
      ).subscribe();
  }

  private buildForm(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

**approuting.ts** file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.component';
import { ContentLayoutComponent } from './layouts/content-layout/content-layout.component';

import { CONTENT_ROUTES } from '../app/shared';

import { NoAuthGuard } from '../app/core';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/auth/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContentLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [NoAuthGuard],
    children: CONTENT_ROUTES
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
  },
  // Fallback when no prior routes is matched
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/auth/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: false, useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],

})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**content-layout.routes.ts** file:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const CONTENT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('../../modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'organization',
    loadChildren: () => import('../../modules/organization/organization.module').then(m => 
    m.OrganizationModule)
  },
];
```

**content-layout.component.html** file:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <app-nav></app-nav>
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">
      <app-breadcrumb id="breadcrumb"></app-breadcrumb>
      <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

**home.routing.ts** file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Dashboard' }
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are a couple of strange things in your routes. One of them is the fact that you have  two different routes assigned to an empty path (the login page and the content layout component). I don't think it should be like that, the content layout component should be assigned to the empty path, and the Auth guard should be redirecting to the login page when the user is not authenticated. You also don't have a default route in content route? Could you share your NoAuthGuard code and tell us if the path for the app changes after the reload?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the wrapper element in *content-layout.component.html* file was 100% high, and because it was the root element, the height calculation could not be correctly.
I changed the height from 100% to 100vh and it works :)